# Obtener parámetros de un procedimiento almacenado Postgres

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

tengo un procedimiento en postres que reporta dos variables, la definicion del procedimiento es esta

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION factura_grabacabecera(
pid bigint,
pdocumento character varying,
INOUT pnumero bigint,
pserie character varying,
pcliente_id bigint,
pfecha date,
INOUT pnota_contable character varying,
paccion character varying)
```

Desde laravel lo llamo de la siguiente forma

```
try{
                $input = $request->all();
                DB::beginTransaction();
                $results=DB::select('SELECT factura_grabacabecera(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                            [$input['id'],
                            $input['documento'],
                            $input['numero'],
                            $input['serie'],
                            $input['cliente_id'],
                            $input['fecha'],
                            $input['fecha_pago'],
                            $input['precio_id'],
                            $input['referencia'],
                            $input['observacion'],
                            $input['vendedor_id'],
                            $input['nota_contable'],
                            $input['subtotal'],
                           ...
                        ]);
                DB::commit();
                return $this->insertOk($results);


            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                DB::rollBack();
                return $this->insertErr(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
            }
```

Funciona bien y me retona esto

```
{
"err": false,
"message": "Registrado correctamente",
"data": [
    {
        "factura_grabacabecera": "(14,FE000000014)"
    }
]
```

}

ahora lo que necesito es tomar los valores de retorno y asigar a una variable el 14 y a otra el FE000000014,
Cual es la mejor forma de hacerlo?
intento de esta forma

```
$res=$results[0]->factura_grabacabecera;
```

pero en $res tengo todo en un string, como tomo solo el segundo valor de retorno por ejemplo

Gracias espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo. Una sería convertir el string en un arreglo, ya que tienes un separador que es la coma ",". De esta forma:

```
 <?php

 $factura_grabacabecera = "(14,FE000000014)";

 //Para eliminar los parentesis del string
 $factura_grabacabecera = trim($factura_grabacabecera, '()');
 
 $factura_array = explode (",", $factura_grabacabecera); 
 
 print_r($factura_array);

/*
Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => FE000000014
)

*/
```

Como última recomendación trabaja con los Modelos de Laravel al momento de hacer las consultas a la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias amigo lo voy  probar, pero ahi tengo una consulta, como recomiendas utilizar modelos en estos casos, lo que hago es llamar a un procedimiento almacenado que retorna uno o mas valores que no necesariamente son modelos.  Ahi es mejor crear un modelo por cada valor o valores que retorna los procedimientos almacenados??